# Why does this triple quoting solution fix path error?

Tags: python, path, escaping, parentheses, os.system

So I was running into a bit of a problem today with this bit of code:

```
os.system("C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.72\dosbox.exe")
```

Upon execution I'd get this error message:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I assumed it was something to do with either the white space or the brackets, so I did a bit of digging online and after countless of ineffective "solutions" involving escape characters, I ended up finding a rather strange solution; to surround the double quotes with another double and a single like so:

```
os.system('""C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.72\dosbox.exe""')
```

I'm confused as to why this works, which I guess isn't very surprising given my lack of python knowledge. I was searching the internet to find out why this works, but to no avail.

So I guess the question is, why does adding those quotes solve the problem?

I'm very new to Python, and programming in general so I'd greatly appreciate any answer to be explained in layman terms.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I wouldn't say this question is a duplicate of the linked one, I was not after a solution to the problem, I already had one. I was curious as to *why* it worked, the logic behind it, so I could better understand the way python works.

Comment: Apparently this is a python quirk that's still unfixed.

Comment: I only needed `r'"c:\program files\fio\fio"` on python2.7 and windows 7  (a different program, but the same issue). The outer `'` tells python its a string and the inner `"` tells the windows shell that the whole string, including spaces, is the filename.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is with the parentheses in Program Files (x86), so you wouldn't have a problem @tdelaney. I think you get that error message when you have a special character in a string attached to os.system, at least that's what I've gathered. I'm using python 2.7 and windows 8.

Comment: Actually never mind, `os.system(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\..."')` worked too.

Comment: @Polaris It won't if you add arguments, read the question I linked.