# How to run a .bat file in DOSbox with Python?

Tags: python, windows, dosbox

I need to use [DOSbox](https://www.dosbox.com) emulator to run a .bat file

But I do not know to implement all the steps that I have to follow in python. This was my try:

```
import os
commands = ['""C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.73\dosbox.exe""',
            'mount c c:\Users\g\Desktop',
            'C:',
            'run_t2d.bat']

for i in commands:
    os.system(i)
```

With the first element it runs the DOSbox console, but then It does not recognise the other 2 commands.

```
'mount' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'run_t2d.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Probably something related to the different subprocess. Of course if I run myself the console and type exactly the same commands it works

Comment: what is `os.curdir` in this case?

Comment: I assume this is windows?

Comment: Why do you think that the other commands would be run within DOSbox?

Comment: Why do you have double double quotes around the first command — try `'"C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.73\dosbox.exe"',` Also, `mount` is not a DOS (or Windows) command.

Comment: @martineau does DOSbox have as command flag that they could be trying to feed with the `mount` line?

Comment: I don't know about a command flag. I think the problem is you're trying to send commands from a Python script running on the host system to a DOS command shell (`command.com`) running on the DOSBox emulator. Look in the DOSBox instructions or manual and see if there's a way to pass it a list of commands at startup.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams If I ask is because I do not have previous experience with this. So I assume I am doing something wrong...

Comment: @martineau check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153632/why-does-this-triple-quoting-solution-fix-path-error

Comment: it is windows but it is not the windows console. It is an emulator called DOSbox. In this case it is used cause the bat file calls to an exe file that only runs with old versions of windows.

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't even need Python for this. You need to run Dosbox passing in a -conf parameter which points to a configuration file with your required commands in an auto exec section.

So if you create a configuration file called something like run_t2d.conf in the same directory as the batch file which looks like this:

```
[autoexec]
mount c c:\Users\g\Desktop
C:
run_t2d.bat
```

Then when you start dosbox:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.73\dosbox.exe -conf C:\Users\G\Desktop\run_t2d.conf`

Of course you could just call that in your python script if you want to.

Comment: Unfortunately this is just a small part inside of a python routine so it has to be done in python. I tried to create the -conf file and then call it from python with no success . os.system('""C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.73\dosbox.exe -conf C:\Users\G\Desktop\run_t2d.conf""') or os.system('""C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.73\dosbox.exe ""'+"-conf C:\Users\G\Desktop\run_t2d.conf")

Comment: What shows on the dos box screen? Does it show anything different from when you just open it normally?

Comment: Try `os.system(r'""C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.73\dosbox.exe" -conf "C:\Users\G\Desktop\run_t2d.conf""')`. This uses a raw string to avoid creating control characters such as `"\r"` (carriage return); wraps both file paths in double quotes (technically not required for the 2nd path since it doesn't have spaces); and wraps the entire command in quotes to get around a legacy quirk in how `cmd /c` parses the command line.

Comment: But you don't need the cmd shell for this and could instead use `subprocess.call(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.73\dosbox.exe" -conf "C:\Users\G\Desktop\run_t2d.conf"')`.

Comment: awesome @eryksun. You got the solution. Thanks Shane Haw quite close.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`-c` option to DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Usage) to specify commands to run as arguments without having to create configuration file. For example:

```
import subprocess

dosbox_exe = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.73\dosbox.exe'
dosbox_args = [r'mount c c:\Users\g\Desktop',
           'C:',
           'run_t2d.bat']

def run_dosbox(args):
    return subprocess.call(reduce(lambda x, y: x + ["-c"] + [y],
                                  args, [dosbox_exe]))

run_dosbox(dosbox_args)
```

I've used `subprocess.call` instead of `os.system` because it automatically handles quoting the arguments where necessary.

Comment: @eryksun It automatically handles quoting the arguments in the form DOSBox expects.

Comment: Is there a way to send a keystroke to the program (bat file) opened in the dosbox?